# Call a function after an event of selecting a checkbox by class or name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox like

```
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something">
```

And there are more than 100 such checkboxes i have to delete multiple data,I cant use id to identify them in DOM any idea how to do something on checkbox select

something like

```
<script>
 $('.mycheck:checkbox:checked').change(function() {
      alert("helloo");   
    });

</script>
```

I want to store checkbox value in array after this event

Comment: `$('.mycheck:checkbox').......` remove `:checked` selector

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to refer the current element inside the event handler function:

```js
$('.mycheck:checkbox').change(function() {
  if(this.checked)
    console.log('checked');
  else
    console.log('not checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the checkbox values when it is checked like below example.

**Example:**

```js
 $('.mycheck:checkbox').change(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked"))
     alert("helloo");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected1' value="something">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected2' value="something">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a checkbox is checked by using `this.checked`. And then alert if the checkbox is checked. So you only need to target such element `$('.mycheck')`:

```js
$('.mycheck').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      alert("Checked!");
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:checked` selector when binding event handlers and `.map()` along with `.filter()` can be used to get the selected values in an array.

```js
var selectedValues;
var checkboxes = $('.mycheck:checkbox').change(function() {
  selectedValues = checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  console.log(selectedValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected1' value="something1">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected2' value="something2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a array in global scope and use that to push and remove the values based on the checkbox checked and unchecked:

```js
var value = [];
$('.mycheck').change(function() {
  var cbValue = $(this).val();
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    value.push(cbValue);
  } else {
    value.splice(value.indexOf(cbValue), 1);
  } 
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something2">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something3">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected' value="something">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected1' value="something1">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected2' value="something2">
<input type='checkbox' class='mycheck' name='selected2' value="something3">
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            const arrayA = [];
            var i = 1;

            $('.mycheck:checkbox').change(function() {
                if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
                    arrayA.push($(this).val()); // store value in array                     
                } else {
                    // use if uncheck checkbox
                }
            });
        });
```

to show you array

```
console.log(arrayA);
```